# Calculate matrix to power 101

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

Being given that

A = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1  \\ 1  \\ -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
and B = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1  &2 &-1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,

Calculate C = $A \cdot B$ and $C^{101}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A.B=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2&-1\\1&2&-1&\\-1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

> $$\begin{pmatrix}x&2x&-x\\x&2x&-x\\-x&-2x&x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x&2x&-x\\x&2x&-x\\-x&-2x&x\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}x^2&2x^2&-x^2\\x^2&2x^2&-x^2\\-x^2&-2x^2&x^2\end{pmatrix}$$

now, $$C^2=4\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&2&-1\\-1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$$$$C^3=16\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&2&-1\\-1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$$$$\vdots$$$$C^{n+1}=4^n\begin{pmatrix}1&2 &-1\\1&2&-1\\-1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence,
$$C^{101}=4^{100}\begin{pmatrix}1 &2&-1\\1&2&-1&\\-1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}=4^{100}C$$

Comment: Good answer. The pattern is very clear. A formal induction argument is needed though.

Comment: And why is it wrong, can you elaborate

Comment: Can you recheck now again? I hope all is right

Comment: Made $C^{n-1}\to C^{n+1}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :** $C^{101}=A \cdot (B \cdot A)^{100} \cdot B$

Comment: How does that help??

Comment: $B \cdot A$ is a scalar, then it is easy to compute the $100$th-power. @neonpokharkar

Comment: Also, interpretation: $C^3=AB\cdot AB\cdot AB=A(BA)(BA)B=A(BA)^2B$.

Comment: OH, now i see it!